# How to replace string keeping associated info in python

Tags: python, regex

Given an **ordered** list of words with associated info (or a list of tuples). I want to replace some of the strings with others but keep track of the associated info.

Let's say that we have a simple case where our input data is two list:

```
words = ["hello", "I", "am", "I", "am", "Jone", "101"]
info = ["1", "3", "23", "4", "6", "5", "12"]
```

input could also be just a list of tuples:

```
list_tuples = list(zip(words, info)))
```

Each item of "list_words" has an associated item (with the same index) from "list_info". e.g. "hello" corresponds to "1" and the second "I" corresponds to "4".

I want to apply some normalization rules to transform them into:

```
words = ["hello", "I'm", "I'm", "Jone", "one hundred and one"]
info = ["1", ["3", "23"], ["4", "6"], "5", "12"]
```

or to another possible solution:

```
words = ["hello", "I'm", "I'm", "Jone", "one", "hundred", "and", "one"]
info = ["1", ["3", "23"], ["4", "6"], "5", "12", "12", "12", "12"]
```

Note this is a simple case, and the idea is to apply multiple normalization rules (numbers to words, substitutions, other contractions, etc.). I know how to transform my string into another using regex, but in that case, I am losing the associated information:

```
def normalize_texts_loosing_info(text):
  # Normalization rules
  text = re.sub(r"I am", "I\'m", text)
  text = re.sub(r"101", "one hundred and one", text)
  # other normalization rules. e.g.
  # text = re.sub(r"we\'ll", "we will", text)
  # text = re.sub(r"you are", "you\'re", text)
  # ....
  return text.split()

words = ["hello", "I", "am", "I", "am", "Jone", "101"]
print(words)
print(" ".join(words))
output = normalize_texts(" ".join(words))
print(output)
```

Question is: How can I apply some transformations to an **ordered** string/list of words but keep the associated info of those words?

PD: Thank you for all the useful comments

Comment: The request is too broad... can you restrict the scope? Maybe give some more examples of "apply some transformation"

Comment: Thanks, I have just added some examples of "apply some transformation."

Comment: Why two lists instead of a list of tuples? That would make it way easier to keep the information in sync.

Comment: It could be also a list of tuples of course. No requirement on that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `partial` matching capability of the the [`regex`](https://pypi.org/project/regex/) library, one can keep track of which patterns might still be applicable.

```
def apply_transformations(words_infos: list[tuple[str, Any]], transformations: dict[regex.Pattern, tuple[str, ...]]) \
        -> list[tuple[str, Any]]:
    # Create the list which we modify to create the result
    result = words_infos.copy()
    # Keep track of the difference between the lengths of input and output
    offset = 0

    # Apply a transformation of tokens [start, end) replacing them with the tokens in new
    # During that we collect together the infos of all input tokens into one tuple,
    # then we copy this info to all new tokens we create
    # Afterwards we update `offset`
    def apply(start: int, end: int, new: tuple[str, ...]):
        nonlocal offset
        print(start, end, new, offset)
        new_info = tuple(words_infos[i][1] for i in range(start, end))
        if len(new_info) == 1:
            new_info, = new_info
        result[start + offset: end + offset] = [(w, new_info) for w in new]
        offset -= (end - start) - len(new)

    # Keep track of partial matches that might still be applied
    partials = []
    for i, (word, info) in enumerate(words_infos):
        new_partials = []
        # Try all patterns starting at this token
        for pattern, res in transformations.items():
            if m := pattern.fullmatch(word, partial=True):
                if m.partial:  # We have a partial match, add it to the backlog
                    new_partials.append((pattern, i, word))
                else:
                    # Apply this transformation immediately, replacing only this token.
                    apply(i, i + 1, res)
                    partials = []  # After applying something, we completely aboard everything else going on
                    new_partials = []
                    break
        # Look thought the backlog, add the current token to them and check if the pattern is now fully applied.
        for pattern, first, prefix in partials:
            if m := pattern.fullmatch(prefix + " " + word, partial=True):
                if m.partial:
                    new_partials.append((pattern, first, prefix + " " + word))
                else:
                    apply(first, i + 1, transformations[pattern])
                    new_partials = []
                    break
        partials = new_partials
    return result
```

This function makes use of the more sane `list[tuple]` representation of the data instead of keep two lists in sync. The transformations are defined as a mapping from `regex.Pattern` instances (i..e not regexes themself) to sequences of strings. If you want more complex transformations, i.e. more similar to the input of `re.sub` you can fiddle around with that by replacing the values in the `transformations` dict and modifying the local `apply` function.

```
def main():
    words = ["hello", "I", "am", "I", "am", "Jone", "101"]
    info = ["1", "3", "23", "4", "6", "5", "12"]

    word_infos = list(zip(words, info, strict=True))

    transformations = {
        regex.compile(r"I am"): ("I\'m",),
        regex.compile(r"101"): ("one hundred and one",)
    }
    result = apply_transformations(word_infos, transformations)
    print(result)
```

Answer (score 2):

IIUC and if the order is not important, a naïve approach would be to iterate through each word of the string to replace and store their values (*if any*) in a temporary dict that will be merged later with a copy of the original one :

```
dict_string = {"hello": 1, "I":2, "am":4, "Jone":6} # original OP

from string import punctuation as pct
from defaultdict import list

def normalize_texts(d, o, t):
    _d = d.copy()
    tmp = defaultdict(list)
    o = o.translate(str.maketrans(pct, " " * len(pct)))

    for w in o.split():
        tmp[t].append(_d.pop(w))

    return dict(_d | tmp)
```

Test/Output :

```
lst = [("I am", "I'm"), ("hello Jone", "Hi Jack")]

for pair in lst:
    print(normalize_texts(dict_string, *pair))
    
{'hello': 1, 'Jone': 6, "I'm": [2, 4]}
{'I': 2, 'am': 4, 'Hi Jack': [1, 6]}
```

Comment: Your answer is very good and thank you for that. However, I have not defined the problem correctly because the order is important for me and in fact, I think I should not dictionaries. I have modified the question.

Comment: What are the rules of the ordering ? The replacement string should be inserted at the position of the first word to be replaced or what exactly ? Can you give a clear logic ? Also, I see that you changed completely your question.

Comment: The order is the natural order of the index in the original list.

Comment: You changed 95% of your question. So it becomes a moving target and the community may think that my answer is absolutely non sense ;)

Comment: Your answer was very good, but I did not defined my problem properly because the order was important, and in fact, the dictionary was not a proper object to keep info in this case. You helped me greatly with that, and I apologise for modifying the original question.

Comment: Could we have `words = ["hello", "I", "_", "am", "I", "am", "Jone", "101"]`. I mean can the words to be replaced be non adjacent ? Are they always ordered ?

Comment: In that case the first "I", "_", "am" should be kept, and only the second "I" "am" should be modified. The rules are strict and only apply to adjacent words like in natural language.

Answer (score 1):

NOTE: This is not a definitive answer... it's more of a suggestion.

Instead of trying to "normalize" the string you create using `join()`, why don't you try working with a `list` of the dictionary's keys? This approach will require you to iterate over the keys, and you could maybe define rules like so:

```py
keys = list(dict_string.keys())

i = 0

while i < len(keys):
    # rule 1
    if keys[i]=='I' and keys[i+1]=='am':
        L = [i,i+1]
        output_string["I'm"] = L
        i += 1 # since we've already looked at i+1
    
    # rule 2
    elif number_to_words_condition:
        ...
    else:
        output_string[keys[i]] = i
    
    i += 1
```

Of course, you will have to perhaps use `try` and `except` to avoid an `IndexError` in case you encounter an "I" at the end of the dictionary, for example.

Answer (score 0):

There is a handy num2words module that translate numbers to words.
using that and a list. Now with order preservation. Converting back to dictionary.

```
from collections import OrderedDict
from num2words import num2words

dict_string = {"hello": 1, "I":2, "am":4, "Jone":6, "101":99}

# convert to list of tuples to be able to insert at position
t_lst = list(dict_string.items())
temp = []
values = []
index = 0

list_of_joined_keys = ["I", "am"]

for t in t_lst:
    k, v = t
    if k.isnumeric():
        new_key = num2words(int(k))
        temp.append((new_key,v))
    elif k in list_of_joined_keys:
        values.append(v)
        index += 1
    else:
        temp.append(t)

joined_key = "'".join(list_of_joined_keys)
temp.insert(index - 1, (joined_key, values)) 

pprint(OrderedDict(temp))

OrderedDict([('hello', 1),
             ("I'am", [2, 4]),
             ('Jone', 6),
             ('one hundred and one', 99)])
```